# Area of a sphere via surface integral

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, surface-integrals

As an example for the computation of the area of a surface of rotation with surface integrals, my textbook derives the formula for the area of a sphere of radius $R$.

The sphere is described by $x^2+y^2+z^2=R^2$. In order to be able to use $Area=2\pi\int\limits_{a}^{b}{r\sqrt{1+\phi'(r)^2dr}}$, we parametrize the top half of the sphere like so: $z=\phi(x)=\sqrt{R^2-x^2}$ $(0\leq{R})$, before rotating it around the $z$-axis.

How did we get this parametrization? Where did $y^2$ disappear to?

Comment: You're looking at the portion of the sphere in the x-z plane (i.e a circle). Then, revolving it around an axis will give you the sphere

Comment: Ah right of course I'm revolving a circle so 2d, obviously... Thanks!